# Change user role based on total number of items ordered

Tags: functions, user-roles

Trying to get this function to work. The first one works fine, it gets the total number of items ordered by a user (all time) and the second one is supposed to change user role based on the total items.

```
function get_user_total_purchased_items( $user_id = 0 ){
global $wpdb;

$customer_id = $user_id === 0 ? get_current_user_id() : (int) $user_id;

return (int) $wpdb->get_var( "
    SELECT SUM(woim.meta_value)
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS woi
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p ON woi.order_id = p.ID
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON woi.order_id = pm.post_id
    WHERE woi.order_item_type = 'line_item'
    AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
    AND p.post_status IN ('wc-completed')
    AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_customer_user'
    AND pm.meta_value LIKE '$customer_id'
    AND woim.meta_key LIKE '_qty'
" );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'change_role_on_purchase', 20, 2 );
function change_role_on_purchase( $order_id, $order ) {

$user_id   = $order->get_customer_id();
$user      = new WP_User( $customer_id );
$purchases = get_user_total_purchased_items( $customer_id );

if( $purchases >= 50 &&  $purchases < 100 && ! in_array( 'bronze_user', $user->roles ) ) {
    // Remove role
    $user->remove_role( 'subscriber' );

    // Add role
    $user->add_role( 'bronze_user' );
}
elseif( $purchases >= 100 &&  $purchases < 200 && ! in_array( 'silver_user', $user->roles ) ) {
    // Remove role
    $user->remove_role( 'bronze_user' );

    // Add role
    $user->add_role( 'silver_user' );
}
elseif( $purchases >= 200 && ! in_array( 'gold_user', $user->roles ) ) {
    // Remove role
    $user->remove_role( 'silver_user' );

    // Add role
    $user->add_role( 'gold_user' );
}

}
```

Anyone have any ideas why its not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You are using a wrong Parameter '$customer_id' that is not defined in your code. Check below is updated code. It should be work. replace below code with your function.

```
function change_role_on_purchase( $order_id, $order ) {

    $user_id   = $order->get_customer_id();
    $user      = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $purchases = get_user_total_purchased_items( $user_id );

    if( $purchases >= 50 &&  $purchases < 100 && ! in_array( 'bronze_user', $user->roles ) ) {
        // Remove role
        $user->remove_role( 'subscriber' );

        // Add role
        $user->add_role( 'bronze_user' );
    }
    elseif( $purchases >= 100 &&  $purchases < 200 && ! in_array( 'silver_user', $user->roles ) ) {
        // Remove role
        $user->remove_role( 'bronze_user' );

        // Add role
        $user->add_role( 'silver_user' );
    }
    elseif( $purchases >= 200 && ! in_array( 'gold_user', $user->roles ) ) {
        // Remove role
        $user->remove_role( 'silver_user' );

        // Add role
        $user->add_role( 'gold_user' );
    }

}
```